# How to use 'edit' function in responsive calendar (w3widgets)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, calendar

I use this calendar http://w3widgets.com/responsive-calendar/
I need to display some events after the page loaded so i add with ajax and the 'edit' function.

the load function looks like this:

```
function loadcalendar(){
          $('#calendar').responsiveCalendar('clearAll');
          $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'getcalendar.php',
            data: {},
            success: function (response)
            {
              $('#calendar').responsiveCalendar('edit', response);
            }
          });
```

the php file returns something like:

```
{\"2014-04-30\": {\"number\": 1, \"badgeClass\": \"badge-warning\"}}
```

the problem ist, that it properly clears all events so the id should be correct
the 'edit' function seems also be working fine cause it display correctly when i input the event directly (instead of the variable)

Answer (score 0):

$.parseJSON(response);

worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example to get leaves for each month from ajax. There must be a better way to do it, but this solved my problem.

```html
     $('.panel-heading').on('click',
                function(firstDay,lastDay) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: "ViewPlannedLeaveJson",
                            data: { dateFrom: formatDate(firstDay), dateTo: formatDate(lastDay) },
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function(result) {
                                $($(currentTag).next('.panel-body').children('.responsive-calendar')[0])
                                    .responsiveCalendar({
                                        onDayClick: function(events) { console.log('Click is Disabled') },
                                        onMonthChange: function () {                                 
                                            GetLeaves(this);
                                        },
                                                events:
                                            JSON.parse(result)
                                        });
                            },
                            error: function(response) {
                                alert("error has occured while retreiving leaves for this user");
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });



    function GetLeaves(currentCalender) {

            var year = currentCalender.currentYear;
            var month = currentCalender.currentMonth ;

            var firstDay = new Date(year, month, 1);
            var lastDay = new Date(year, month + 1, 0);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "ViewPlannedLeaveJson",
                data: {dateFrom: formatDate(firstDay), dateTo: formatDate(lastDay) },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(result) {
//Edit Code
                    $($(currentCalender)[0].$element).responsiveCalendar('edit', JSON.parse(result)
                );
                },
                error: function(response) {
                    alert("error has occured while retreiving leaves for this month");
                }
            });
        }
```